# search button is fixed not moving

Tags: html, css, css-float, html5-canvas

to move the search text button and search button i gave margin left....
but when i re size the browser window the search button remains stationary....
how to make it move with respect to title and wisth....
the search input box and select menu should be on the right end of the screen

http://jsfiddle.net/nb6WP/1/

Bom Creation Form

```
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: you should be pasting the code relevant to this specific button in addition to giving a jsfiddle, we are trying to help but we don't want to look through all of your code when you can just give us the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

give the `margin -left` percentage `10%` value not pixel `20px`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `float: right;` that should send the elements all the way to the right and position correctly on a resize. Also note the change in order of the search button.

```
<input name="Finish" value="Search" class="checkout-button searchButton" type="submit" style="width: 107px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px; background-color: #666; float: right;">
<input class="span2" type="password" style="float: right;">

      <select  style="float: right;">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Well, I'm pointing you towards the CSS rule `float: right`. I cannot be any clearer, I'm assuming by your code you at least have some experience with CSS, so I can't really do anymore. You could try doing a little research on it if you still have doubts.